# How to pass multiple status messages from controller to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to pass status messages from the controller, which contains multiple methods, to the view via JSON.

There are 3 bool methods in a different controller which validates the connection string to sql server, creates the connection string in web.config, then creates the database:

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult ConfigurationService(ConfigurationServiceModel Model)
    {
        TempData["dbHost"] = Model.dbHost;
        TempData["dbName"] = Model.dbName;
        TempData["dbLogonName"] = Model.dbLogonName;
        TempData["dbPassword"] = Model.dbPassword;
        
        //Validate connection string
        if(ValidateConnectionString(Model.dbHost, Model.dbName, Model.dbLogonName, Model.dbPassword) == true)
        {
```

> @here, I would like to do something along the lines of
> `return Json(new { status = "Successfully validated ConnectionString" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

But if I do that, I will end up getting "unreachable code" for anything below.

```
            //Create connection string and database and store connection string in web.config
            if (CreateConnectionString(Model.dbHost, Model.dbName, Model.dbLogonName, Model.dbPassword) == true)
            {
```

> and another one @here,
> `return Json(new { status = "Successfully created ConnectionString" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
> }

```
            if (!CreateDB(Model.dbHost, Model.dbName, Model.dbLogonName, Model.dbPassword) == true)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error creating database");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Error verifying connection string");
        }
        
        return View();
    }
```

**The Ajax from the View for submitting:**

```
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventdefault;

            if ($("#frmConfigurationService")[0].checkValidity()) {
                spinner.removeAttribute("hidden");
                $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
            }

            else
                //Validate Form
                $("#frmConfigurationService")[0].reportValidity()

            var formData = $('#frmConfigurationService').serialize();

            $.post("/Home/ConfigurationService", formData)
                .always(function (data) {
                    spinner.removeAttribute("hidden");
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    spinner.setAttribute("hidden", "");
                    $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
                    toastr.success(data.status, 'Success');
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .fail(function (data) {
                    spinner.setAttribute("hidden", "");
                    $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
                    console.log(data);
                    toastr.error(data.responseJSON.errorMessage, 'Error');
                });
        });
```

Uncertain on how to accomplish this, would it be advised to do it as a collection list containing the status messages?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is better to create a collection of the status messages and return back to the caller.

But even better is to just display the final message to the user that everything was completed as expected.

And if you need to read status messages as they happen for debugging purposes, I suggest logging them in the backend only.